# How do I conditionally render certain data while using useEffect and setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, conditional-statements

I have a parent component EventPage and a child component UpcomingEvent. In the UpcomngEvent component I have my useEffect (not sure if it should be there or in the EventPage component. What I am trying to do is: if there is an upcoming event I want a certain section of code to render, if the upcoming event is null I want to render a different section of code.
Here is the code from UpcomingEvent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import UpcomingShowFlyerDesktop from 'assets/images/flyer-desktop.png'
import UpcomingShowFlyerMobile from 'assets/images/flyer-mobile.png'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from '../styles'

function UpcomingEvent({ title, date, location, about }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [upcomingEvent, setUpcomingEvent] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    setUpcomingEvent(
      (upcomingEvent) =>
        ({
          ...upcomingEvent,
          title: title,
          date: date,
          location: location,
          about: about,
        }[title][date][location][about])
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.upcomingShowsMobile}>
        <div className={classes.titleContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleMobile}>
            {title}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.dateLocationContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationMobile}>
            {date} | {location}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.aboutContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowMobile}>
            {about}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.upcomingShowButtonContainerMobile}>
          <button className={classes.upcomingShowButtonMobile}>
            BUY TICKETS
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the parent component EventPage:

```
const EventsPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(EVENTS)
  // const startDate = '04/23/2021'
  // const endDate = '05/04/2021'
  return (
    <div>
      {/*-------------Mobile View--------------------- */}
      <Grid
        container
        direction='column'
        justify='center'
        alignItems='center'
        spacing={0}
        className={classes.allContainerMobile}
      >
        <div className={classes.headingContainerMobile}>
          <div>
            <p className={classes.allEventsTitleMobile}>ALL EVENTS</p>
          </div>
          {UpcomingEvent === null ? (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.parentDivImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.ImageDivMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={EventsHeroImageMobile}
                    className={classes.placeHolderImageMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid item sm={12} className={classes.gridMobile}>
                <div className={classes.countdownContainerMobile}>
                  <div className={classes.countdownParentMobile}>
                    <CountdownTimer
                      countdown={startDate}
                      unixEndDate={endDate}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
          {UpcomingEvent === null ? (
            <div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowMobile}>UPCOMING SHOW</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsMobile}>
                  NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.flyerImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.upcomingShowParentMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={UpcomingShowFlyerMobile}
                    className={classes.imageStyleMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        {UpcomingEvent !== null ? (
          <div>
            <UpcomingEvent
              title={title}
              date={date}
              location={location}
              about={about}
            />
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {UpcomingEvent === null ? (
          <div>
            <h2 className={classes.pastShowsMobile}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h2 className={classes.pastShowsUpcomingMobile}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
          </div>
        )}

        <div className={classes.eventsCardMobile}>
          {events.map(({ month, day, title, time, location }, i) => (
            <BasicCard
              key={`${title}-${i}`}
              month={month}
              day={day}
              title={title}
              time={time}
              location={location}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: Looking at your code; it seems the supposed-to-be parent component `EventPage` never renders `UpcomingEvent` (it just renders some JSX depending on whether `UpcomingEvent` is `null` or not). Also, in `UpcomingEvent` you are listing the `useEffect()` dependencies in the wrong way and in the wrong position in the code.

Comment: Combining your conditional ternary statements will make this easier to manage.

Comment: @secan I do render UpcomingEvent towards the bottom of the page. What would be the correct way to list the dependencies in useEffect?

Comment: @Irfaan, I’m a bit confused about combing ternary statements. Could you share an example so I can better understand your meaning?

Comment: @SherreAhlers You could replace the two `UpcomingEvent === null ?` statements with one, by combining the truthy parts i.e. the parts after the `?` and also combining the falsy parts i.e. the parts after the `:`.

Additionally, `UpcomingEvent !== null` is just the opposite of the above statement. So you could move this one's truthy part into the falsy part of the one above and vice-versa.

Think about it as a shorthand `if-else` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I was placing my useEffect hook in the wrong place, and with the wrong criteria. After much struggle the answer finally came to me (and with the help of the people who left comments.
This is the new and improved EventsPage:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import BasicCard from 'pages/EventsPage/EventsCard/index'
import UpcomingEvent from 'pages/EventsPage/UpcomingEvent/UpcomingEvent'
import UpcomingShowFlyerMobile from 'assets/images/flyer-mobile.png'
import EventsHeroImage from 'assets/images/events-hero-image.jpg'
import EventsHeroImageMobile from 'assets/images/events-mobile-hero-image.jpeg'
import CountdownTimer from 'pages/EventsPage/CountdownTimer/CountdownTimer'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from './styles'

const EVENTS = [
  {
    month: 'AUG',
    day: '09',
    title: 'SUMMER 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
  {
    month: 'APR',
    day: '17',
    title: 'SPRING 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
  {
    month: 'AUG',
    day: '09',
    title: 'FALL 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
  {
    month: 'APR',
    day: '17',
    title: 'WINTER 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
]

const UPCOMINGEVENT = [
  {
    title: 'WINTER 2020 SHOWCASE',
    date: 'JAN 24TH',
    location: 'THE IRENIC, SAN DIEGO',
    about:
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Consectetur cursus nunc faucibus justo enim, eget dignissim lacus turpis. Tincidunt sed mauris in volutpat. Sapien fringilla libero, facilisis elementum nisi lobortis amet porttitor. Velit risus diam sit feugiat velit enim et, euismod quis.',
  },
]
// const UPCOMINGEVENT = [
//   {
//     title: null,
//     date: null,
//     location: null,
//     about: null,
//   },
// ]

const EventsPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(EVENTS)
  const [upcomingEvent, setUpcomingEvent] = useState(UPCOMINGEVENT)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (upcomingEvent !== null) {
      setUpcomingEvent(UPCOMINGEVENT)
    } else {
      null
    }
  }, [upcomingEvent])

  const startDate = '04/23/2021'
  const endDate = '05/04/2021'
  return (
    <div>
      {/*-------------Mobile View--------------------- */}
      <Grid
        container
        direction='column'
        justify='center'
        alignItems='center'
        spacing={0}
        className={classes.allContainerMobile}
      >
        <div className={classes.headingContainerMobile}>
          <div>
            <p className={classes.allEventsTitleMobile}>ALL EVENTS</p>
          </div>
          {upcomingEvent === null ? (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.parentDivImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.ImageDivMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={EventsHeroImageMobile}
                    className={classes.placeHolderImageMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid item sm={12} className={classes.gridMobile}>
                <div className={classes.countdownContainerMobile}>
                  <div className={classes.countdownParentMobile}>
                    <CountdownTimer
                      countdown={startDate}
                      unixEndDate={endDate}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
          {upcomingEvent === null ? (
            <div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowMobile}>UPCOMING SHOW</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsMobile}>
                  NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.flyerImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.upcomingShowParentMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={UpcomingShowFlyerMobile}
                    className={classes.imageStyleMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        {upcomingEvent !== null ? (
          <div>
            {upcomingEvent.map(({ title, date, location, about }) => (
              <UpcomingEvent
                key={title}
                title={title}
                date={date}
                location={location}
                about={about}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {upcomingEvent === null ? (
          <div>
            <h2 className={classes.pastShowsMobile}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h2 className={classes.pastShowsUpcomingMobile}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
          </div>
        )}

        <div className={classes.eventsCardMobile}>
          {events.map(({ month, day, title, time, location }, i) => (
            <BasicCard
              key={`${title}-${i}`}
              month={month}
              day={day}
              title={title}
              time={time}
              location={location}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Grid>
```

and here is the UpcomingEvent component:

```
import UpcomingShowFlyerDesktop from 'assets/images/flyer-desktop.png'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from '../styles'

function UpcomingEvent({ title, date, location, about }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.upcomingShowsMobile}>
        <div className={classes.titleContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleMobile}>{title}</p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.dateLocationContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationMobile}>
            {date} | {location}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.aboutContainerMobile}>
          <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowMobile}>{about}</p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.upcomingShowButtonContainerMobile}>
          <button className={classes.upcomingShowButtonMobile}>
            BUY TICKETS
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UpcomingEvent
```